# How to shut down clustered SQL Server 2008 R2 with NOWAIT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustering

Is it possible to `shutdown with nowait` on a clustered instance? I want to delay recovery to when the instance starts, and I want to shut down as quickly as possible without issuing checkpoints to my clustered instances. If I issue a `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT`, SQL Server sends a `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` message which causes it to go into a `Failed` state. The cluster service then starts it up, which is not what I want.

Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT` is like pulling power cable out of your server.

Comment: `Ideas?` -- Yes: stop doing that.

Comment: I've done some testing on this and discovered that SQL Server in a cluster ALWAYS does a SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT. Interesting, in that you CAN'T do a graceful shutdown on a cluster. Kind of surprised me... And if you don't believe me test it yourself. BEGIN TRAN, change some data and then take your SQL Server service offline in cluster manager. Start up and see if your transaction is there...

Comment: @MooMinTroll Whether the changes made by your transaction are present after it starts again has do with whether your transaction was committed, not whether SQL Server shut down with NOWAIT.

Comment: @MooMinTroll the `WITH NOWAIT` option --> Shuts down SQL Server without performing checkpoints in every database. SQL Server exits after attempting to terminate all user processes. When the server restarts, a rollback operation occurs for uncompleted transactions.

Comment: @James not true. A graceful shutdown WAITS for the transaction to finish before shutting down. SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT does not wait :) (clue is in the name of the command) so any active transactions will be rolled back.

Comment: @MooMinTroll Assuming Books Online is correct, without `NOWAIT` a `SHUTDOWN` waits for statements (not transactions) to complete.